# Power Saving in Ubuntu ( Linux )

Tags: power, ubuntu-11.04, powertop

I installed the [PowerTop](http://www.linuxpowertop.org/) application in Ubuntu 11.04 and according to it, `npviewer.bin` is consuming more power than other processes.

What is `npviewer.bin`? Why does it take most of the computer's power?

- What if I do `sudo pkill npviewer.bin` ?

Comment: This could be myriad of things. npview.bin is essentially, flash. What version of flash are you running? What version of ubunutu are you running? 64bit? Did you get flash 64bit. What web browser are you running?

Answer (score 3):

It's part of nspluginwrapper. It's probably being used to play Flash, which can be a large power drain.